# Serving sending NULL not being caught by $http request

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, get

The server I'm retrieving data from returns `NULL` when no data is found (I have no control over this server). The issue is the data isn't getting to success or error but just throwing an error. I want to catch the NULL and treat it as a normal response.

```
  var config = {
    method:'GET',
    url:url,
    cache: false,
    params: data
  };
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $http(config).success(function(data) {
      resolve(data);
    }).error(function error(err) {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
```

The promise is being used in the controller:

```
service.getPromise().then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

The exact errors in the console are:

```
ionic.bundle.js:26794 SyntaxError: Unexpected token N in JSON at position 0
Uncaught (in promise) undefined
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add a catch block to catch and resolve the error then you can resolve that response to whatever you want when accessing it in your `getPromise` promise:

```
var config = {
    method:'GET',
    url:url,
    cache: false,
    params: data
};

return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $http(config).success(function(data) {
      resolve(data);
    })
    .error(function error(err) {
      reject(err);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        // your catch logic here

        resolve(null);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment but I end up getting the same error.